# How can I convert data to long format?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(X = 1:100, username = c("Ohh_Ziggy", "WEAVYwonder_", 
"mcbadlon", "NaazhimSupreme", "nivanacampos", "nrazaliyah", "Bigfamlife", 
"_CurlyFryGuy_", "Jackie_montes", "SplendentSweven", "EclecticCoding", 
"RevTinTin", "MiyaDior", "RudyJb1024", "xkimmygirlx", "Crescen04324237", 
"wsrphoto", "Keioney_kisses", "preciousrubie", "Brenderzzz_", 
"kikilovescats", "samanthacraig15", "cappir", "ChildOUniverse", 
"PeachiesPromo", "Bierkast", "terri2kool", "LattaZakyra", "Yildiiiiiiiiz", 
"d1no_nugget", "brendochendo", "thehulkster", "Nick_Miles_", 
"__aubssss", "Warrior_Maiden", "napitupulu_a", "lizziemonkhouse", 
"smutwiizard", "tayzer6", "SimStrength", "popkis", "AnnetteVitelli3", 
"Karabo_Mtaung", "ankushthebest10", "ducksandchucks", "May_leita", 
"anna_michaux", "WayCatPub", "orodelancs", "CoastCyclist", "bluemoon357", 
"danieldurrans", "james_southcott", "CarmelScotsNews", "JanJoostBouwman", 
"100ProofWoman", "undersiegexo", "parrothead34", "amoodyknapp", 
"Maverick1914", "lilac_bun", "TaterSaladJD", "ItsBittie", "gengen0309", 
"MainMandarin", "napitupulu_a", "Ipeethree3", "KLobstar", "simplyaracelii", 
"stankloaf", "CllrKenPollock", "OnlySimphiwe", "IanSmalley3", 
"KathrynwithaY", "msmrocks", "marge_cord", "m_melodias", "spaceboosh", 
"huegolden", "Crampedsultana", "siempreAM0nae", "Herbie555", 
"SandraRPearce1", "reverend_thom", "natashametzler", "charlesdlcruz", 
"Ho8Go8L1N", "_JLovee", "Felstedboy", "Its_Jack_Brooo", "CuddiCAPALOT", 
"iamesrvan", "PickledGingerBC", "boogy1228", "Honeylotus333", 
"ThisOffendsMeTV", "Just_Jones33", "damnnndor", "dbrown13", "DaYy_ShiNeBRITE"
), compound = c(-0.1027, -0.3612, 0.5574, -0.886, 0.4738, 0, 
0.9277, 0, -0.6077, 0.5023, 0.5635, 0, 0, -0.4767, -0.8248, -0.4678, 
-0.296, 0.0094, 0, 0.9274, 0.6124, -0.6664, 0, 0.6486, 0.6116, 
0.5399, 0.8926, 0, 0.6792, 0.9768, 0, 0.2732, -0.7073, 0.892, 
-0.7783, 0.3818, 0, -0.6739, 0.7314, 0.4588, -0.2411, 0, -0.2212, 
0.2023, -0.2244, 0.296, -0.4417, -0.7003, 0.2946, -0.6808, 0, 
0, -0.0387, -0.3816, 0.5106, 0.296, 0.6739, 0.5487, -0.2023, 
0.5229, -0.9559, 0.6369, 0.743, 0, 0, 0.3818, 0, -0.1531, 0.4278, 
0, 0.555, 0, 0.3182, 0, 0.4939, 0.1531, 0, 0.802, 0.7717, 0.624, 
-0.7184, -0.128, 0.1027, 0.6209, 0.3109, -0.6249, 0.4118, -0.6249, 
-0.296, 0.5083, 0.5994, 0.6124, 0.4199, -0.8069, 0.4767, -0.5423, 
0.5994, 0.9153, -0.296, -0.8417), Date = c("2020-03-30", "2020-03-30", 
"2020-03-26", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-18", 
"2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-16", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-05", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-27", 
"2020-02-26", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-02-09", 
"2020-02-07", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-31", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-20", "2020-02-08", "2020-02-07", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-11", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-02-29", "2020-02-27", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-23", 
"2020-02-17", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-15", "2020-03-31", "2020-03-31", 
"2020-03-27", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-20", 
"2020-03-18", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-01", 
"2020-02-29", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-31", 
"2020-03-22", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-19", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-22", 
"2020-02-11", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-25", "2020-02-18", 
"2020-03-17", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-25", 
"2020-02-17", "2020-02-15", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-17", "2020-02-29", 
"2020-03-26", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-15", "2020-02-11", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-15", 
"2020-03-14", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-13", 
"2020-03-29", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-18", 
"2020-02-15", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-31"), agegroup = c("YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "OA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "OA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA"
)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

A username may have one to many observations.
I hope to generate an output to a long format like this:

If time falls between

Date From 2020-03-1 to 2020-05-31 coded as Time “1”

Date From 2020-06-1 to 2020-08-31 coded as Time “2”

Date From 2020-09-1 to 2021-02-28 coded as Time “3”

Date From 2021-03-1 to 2021-04-30 coded as Time “4”

If there are more than 2 scores fall in the time frame, calculate the average.

The output I would like to see is:
For each username, they will have four observations.

```
Username   Agegroup    Score    Time   Date
A            YA         NA       1     Date in the original dataset
A            YA         0.1      2     Date in the original dataset
A            YA         NA       3     Date in the oringal dataset
A            YA         NA       4     ...
B            MA         NA       1     ...
B            MA         NA       2     ...
B            MA         0.2      3     ...
B            MA         0.2      4     ...
```

Comment: is "compound" score in your original data frame?

Comment: Yes, it means Score.

Comment: Hey I think I got the correct behavior now, after a couple edits. check it out! I only have two time frames because that's all that was in the data frame you shared but the code should work for four

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

   df <- df %>%
  mutate(time = case_when(Date >= "2020-02-01" & Date <= "2020-03-01" ~ 1,
                      Date >= "2020-03-01" & Date <= "2020-03-31" ~ 2,
                      Date >= "2020-09-01" & Date <= "2021-02-28" ~ 3,
                      Date >= "2021-03-01" & Date <= "2021-04-30" ~ 4))
                      
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(username, agegroup, time) %>% 
  summarize(score = mean(compound))

df2$username <- as.factor(df2$username)
df2$agegroup <- as.factor(df2$agegroup)

expanded_df <- expand.grid(df2$username, df2$time)

expanded_df <- expanded_df %>%
  distinct()

colnames(expanded_df) <- c("username", "time")

df3 <- full_join(df2, expanded_df, by = c("username", "time"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any chance to let each of the username occur four times? So the total rows would be # of distinct username*4

Comment: Give the username an NA in score if there is no observation in this time range.

Comment: I'm asking myself: Why do you store your data in `df` or `df2` instead of doing the transformation in one big pipe (and store them at the end of the process)?

Comment: I think I got the correct behavior at the end but I fumbled through it. The intermediate tables helped me work through it / investigate step-by-step without having to reload the original tables. If you have suggestions / better way for storing variables at the end I would love to see it. you'll laugh bc I have four data frames now

Comment: Did you have errors?> expanded_df <- expand.grid(df2$username, df2$time)
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
> 
> expanded_df <- expanded_df %>%
+   distinct()
Error in distinct(.) : object 'expanded_df' not found
> 
> colnames(expanded_df) <- c("username", "time")
Error in colnames(expanded_df) <- c("username", "time") : 
  object 'expanded_df' not found
> 
> df3 <- full_join(df2, expanded_df, by = c("username", "time"))
Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'expanded_df' not found

Comment: try sweeping away everything in your local environment and running from the top

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to divide `Date` in 4 intervals. Calculate average value of `compound` for each `username`, `agegroup` and `Time` value. Use `complete` to get all the 4 time values for each `username`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         Time = cut(Date, as.Date(c('2020-03-1', '2020-06-1', '2020-09-1', '2021-03-1', '2021-04-30')), labels = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(username, agegroup, Time) %>%
  summarise(Score = mean(compound, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  complete(username, Time = 1:4)

res
```